# How do I "Use Destination Theme and Link Data" in PowerPoint (MS Office 365 Business)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint, themes

I want to select a table from an Excel file and paste/link it into a PowerPoint presentation with the destination theme, so that if the Excel file is updated, the corresponding PowerPoint presentation reflects the updates made to the Excel spreadsheet.

I have used 'Paste Special' (`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `V`) but can't find the option to use the destination theme.

I do have a company specific theme in PowerPoint, but not in Excel.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think you can have match destination formatting, it will use which ever colour scheme you have selected in each application, hopefully some one can prove me wrong as I have had this issue many times myself

Comment: According to this article you can: https://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/embed-excel-files-in-powerpoint--cms-28978. But I can't find the same options that are used in the article...